# What is the most efficient way to merge both states in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a Grouped List with Infinite Scroll Pagination in React as below.

[image: Application UI]

I'm Grouping items from WEB API using LINQ GroupBy after fetching each page and returning back to client as below JSON format.

[image: JSON format for each page of data]

Now some times groups can repeat and I want to merge the same to avoid duplicate Section Headers.

I tried the below code to do it Immutably

```js
let currentStateClone = [...currentState];

stateNew.forEach((st)=>{
    let itemIndex = currentState.findIndex(x=>x.title===st.title);
    
    if(itemIndex >= 0){
      //Key already existson current state then merge
      currentStateClone = currentState.map((item,index)=>{
            if(index===itemIndex)
                return {...item,data:[...item.data,...st.data]};
            else
               return {...item};
      });
    }else{
     //New Key Found Append
      currentStateClone = currentStateClone.concat(st);
    }
});
```

**Now my question is what is the most *"Performant and Cross Browser way"* to merge these two states (json arrays) in JavaScript ?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please may you show us that effort as a [mcve]?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited the question to include what I actually tried.. Please help me make it performant and efficient.

Comment: Is this currently slow? How do you know it's not peformant already

Comment: @azium I felt I'm doing more clones of objects than necessary. I'm looking is there is any better way to solve this

Comment: @Auticcat that won't deduplicate the objects